# R package 'gfortran' is not available (for R version 3.3.1)

Tags: r, installation, gfortran, r-package

I'm trying to install the package 'gfortran' (because the package 'deSolve' demands it to be insatlled) but get the error:

```
install.packages("gfortran")
Warning in install.packages :
  package 'gfortran' is not available (for R version 3.3.1)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: What OS are you using? gfortran is a system package - not an R package.  Basically you need a fortran compiler on your system (and findable via your system path).

Comment: @Dason I am using MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6... so what do I need to do? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a Mac user so I'm not sure. Xcode maybe? I think that solves some of these issues but it's been years since I've tinkered with Macs so that could be an out of date recommendation. But basically you need to get a Fortran compiler on your path.

Comment: @Dason any idea on how to do it? I really know nothing in this issues

Comment: Xcode maybe. That's all I could suggest. That and googling gfortran for mac

Comment: @Dason what do you mean by Xcode?

Comment: A search engine is your best friend.

Comment: @Dason I tried but still doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722733/cant-install-desolve-pacakge-in-r

Answer (score 0):

You should install gfortran on your device, not in the R console.
The steps you should take are nicely written [here](http://www.lapk.org/gfortran/gfortran.php?OS=7).
In short,

1. Remove existing gfortran installations
2. Install Xcode from the App Store
3. Run in your terminal:

   ```
   xcode-select --install
   ```
4. Install gfortran. You can find all releases [here](https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases)
5. Go back to R and install your desired package